# Android: align labels and buttons in multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I go nuts on that layout. So here's what I'm trying to achieve. A simple layout having a label (TextView) or edit field (EditText) on the left side and a button on the right side. I want all labels and all buttons vertically adjusted - meaning all buttons of the same width and all labels too.

But how to do this? I tried a LinearLayout with vertical orientation and each line as another LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and inside that the label has a layout_weight of 8 and the button is 1. But still this does not guarantee what I want!

This is the current result. You can see that the buttons are not nicely aligned.

[image: the current result]

This is my layout:

[image: the current layout]

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="test_test_blabla"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/action_scan"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="17:35"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/action_pick_time"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to do?I might be able to help out if you give me a bit more details.And also, please tell me ,is this something you want added once, or you want to have instances of it?

Comment: And please don't use the tableLayout...it's a "dumb" workaround...

Comment: I added an answer to my question using the TableLayout. There you will see what I'm trying. All buttons on the right nicely aligned and all of same size. But still the elements on the left side (EditText, TextView) are not using the available width up to the right just before the button starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `RelativeLayout` you can achieve the desired layout as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:hint="test_test_blabla"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:hint="Scan"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:text="17:35"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:hint="Pick Time"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The key layout attribute used to match the size is `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"` on the first `EditText` referencing the `TextView` just below.

## Result:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This is not the correct answer...it's only an workaround for the problem.I am pretty sure there are better,more efficient ways to deal with it and I got one in mind right now but it really looks like people don't care for the optimized answer ,a simple workaround is enough.

Comment: @Vlad You're misguided to think that a flatter `RelativeLayout` as above is a hack and wouldn't perform over a `LinearLayout` like the one OP had. It will and actually be many times better if used in a repeating widget like a `ListView`. Please read up on optimizing layout performances for Android and you'll know that the deeper a layout goes the worse its performance is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

According to people's advise, I used the TableLayout. But still the label (EditText) is not using the whole space til the button.

[image: TableLayout]

That's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="test_test_blabla"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/action_scan"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="17:35"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/action_pick_time"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/hint_car_location_address"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/action_gps"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Not the proper way sir.Please answer my first comment and I will be back with information asap.

Comment: What details are you missing? I already said that I want all buttons of same size on the right and the left EditText fields to use the available space. So basically the TableLayout is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
try RelativeLayout
something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2">
    <EditText
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@android:id/button1"
        android:text="test"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="28dp"
        android:paddingRight="28dp"
        android:text="set"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@android:id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/button1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="some test"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@android:id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/button1"
        android:text="Scan"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

5+ years later...OP  is probably an expert in android xml by now. Nevertheless, to help with the question, linear layout is doable. I've added another linear layout to contain all the rows so that the margins can be adjust in this additional layout.

When weight sum is used, the corresponding variable (width / height) has to be 0dp so that it can be adjust accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:hint="test_test_blabla"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:hint="@string/action_scan"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:text="17:35"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:hint="@string/action_pick_time"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```